# Count median days per ID between one zero and the first transaction after the last zero in a running balance

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a running balance sheet showing customer balances after inflows and (outflows) by date. It looks something like this:

```
ID DATE               AMOUNT RUNNING AMOUNT
-- ----------------  ------- --------------
10 27/06/2019 14:30      100            100
10 29/06/2019 15:26     -100              0
10 03/07/2019 01:56       83             83
10 04/07/2019 17:53       15             98
10 05/07/2019 15:09      -98              0
10 05/07/2019 15:53    98.98          98.98
10 05/07/2019 19:54   -98.98              0
10 07/07/2019 01:36    90.97          90.97
10 07/07/2019 13:02   -90.97              0
10 07/07/2019 16:32    39.88          39.88
10 08/07/2019 13:41       50          89.88
20 08/01/2019 09:03   890.97         890.97
20 09/01/2019 14:47   -91.09         799.88
20 09/01/2019 14:53      100         899.88
20 09/01/2019 14:59     -399         500.88
20 09/01/2019 18:24      311         811.88
20 09/01/2019 23:25       50         861.88
20 10/01/2019 16:18  -861.88              0
20 12/01/2019 16:46   894.49         894.49
20 25/01/2019 05:40  -871.05          23.44
```

I have attempted using `lag()` but I seem not to understand how to use it yet.

```
SELECT ID, MEDIAN(DIFF) MEDIAN_AGE
FROM
(
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(day, Lag(DATE, 1) OVER(ORDER BY ID), DATE
)AS DIFF 
FROM TABLE 1 
WHERE RUNNING AMOUNT = 0 
)
GROUP BY ID;
```

The expected result would be:

```
ID MEDIAN_AGE
-- ----------
10          1
20          2
```

Please help in writing out the query that gives the expected result.

Comment: What is the "median age" and can you better explain what this means?

Comment: What about [MEDIAN](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions111.htm#SQLRF06315)?

Comment: `DATEDIFF` is not an Oracle function. You also can't use `SELECT *, something_else FROM ...` as you would need to qualify the `*` with the table name (or alias).

Comment: Can you give a worked example of the maths that would lead to your expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already pointed out, you are using syntax that isn't valid for Oracle, including functions that don't exist and column names that aren't allowed.

You seem to want to calculate the number of days between a zero running-amount and the following non-zero running-amount; `lead()` is probably easier than `lag()` here, and you can use a case expression to only calculate it when needed:

```
select id, date_, amount, running_amount,
  case when running_amount = 0 then
    lead(date_) over (partition by id order by date_) - date_
  end as diff
from your_table;

        ID DATE_                    AMOUNT RUNNING_AMOUNT       DIFF
---------- -------------------- ---------- -------------- ----------
        10  2019-06-27 14:30:00        100            100           
        10  2019-06-29 15:26:00       -100              0     3.4375
        10  2019-07-03 01:56:00         83             83           
        10  2019-07-04 17:53:00         15             98           
        10  2019-07-05 15:09:00        -98              0 .0305555556
        10  2019-07-05 15:53:00      98.98          98.98           
        10  2019-07-05 19:54:00     -98.98              0     1.2375
        10  2019-07-07 01:36:00      90.97          90.97           
        10  2019-07-07 13:02:00     -90.97              0 .145833333
        10  2019-07-07 16:32:00      39.88          39.88           
        10  2019-07-08 13:41:00         50          89.88           
        20  2019-01-08 09:03:00     890.97         890.97           
        20  2019-01-09 14:47:00     -91.09         799.88           
        20  2019-01-09 14:53:00        100         899.88           
        20  2019-01-09 14:59:00       -399         500.88           
        20  2019-01-09 18:24:00        311         811.88           
        20  2019-01-09 23:25:00         50         861.88           
        20  2019-01-10 16:18:00    -861.88              0 2.01944444
        20  2019-01-12 16:46:00     894.49         894.49           
        20  2019-01-25 05:40:00    -871.05          23.44
```

Then use the `median()` function, rounding if desired to get your expected result:

```
select id, median(diff) as median_age, round(median(diff)) as median_age_rounded
from (
  select id, date_, amount, running_amount,
    case when running_amount = 0 then
      lead(date_) over (partition by id order by date_) - date_
    end as diff
  from your_table
)
group by id;

        ID MEDIAN_AGE MEDIAN_AGE_ROUNDED
---------- ---------- ------------------
        10 .691666667                  1
        20 2.01944444                  2
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=67dc716e8e57b66abf4fa9355b165794)